# Django model creation insists I use auth_user when I created a custom user type

Tags: django, django-users

The code that is causing an error:

```
obj = CustomUser.objects.all()[0]
o = Order(portfolio={'stocks': 'appl'}, user=obj, money=1)
o.save()
```

I'm trying to create a new order object which uses a CustomUser instance

CustomUser is defined as follows:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    id = CharField(max_length=100, default=NO_ACCOUNT)
```

Order is defined as follows:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    portfolio = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    money = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I would expect that I can create this object but the error I'm getting is:

```
insert or update on table "deploy_order" violates foreign key constraint "deploy_order_user_id_b435189b_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(2) is not present in table "auth_user".
```

I'm not sure why auth_user gets looked up when I clearly am using my custom user type. My migrations are up to date.

Comment: 2 Questions: have you defined yout custom user model in your settings.py file as in 
`AUTH_USER_MODEL` and why would you define an ID field? By default, Django gives each model `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` . This is an auto-incrementing primary key. Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: Yes, I've defined it in settings.py. I'm also just creating the models incrementally so I wanted to add some trivial fields. In the future I will get rid of this